# Wpa-supplicant overriding iwconfig

Tags: bash, wpa-supplicant

`Wpa-supplicant` is not clearing its settings when I disconnect, and is overriding `iwconfig` on my next connection. These settings are persisting even through reboot - the only way to get back online is to take wpa-supplicant out of the pipeline.

I disconnect using a script which includes everything I could think of:

```
sudo dhcpcd --release "$INTERFACE"
sudo iwconfig "$INTERFACE" essid off
sudo iwconfig "$INTERFACE" ap off
sudo ifconfig "$INTERFACE" down
```

This worked well until I tried to integrate `wpa-supplicant` in it.

My "connect" script includes these lines, which I thought would clear out any remaining settings:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant 2>/dev/null
sudo rm "/var/run/wpa_supplicant/$INTERFACE" 2>/dev/null
sudo killall dhcpcd 2>/dev/null
sudo rm "/var/lib/dhcpcd/$INTERFACE" 2>/dev/null
```

How do I "reset" `wpa-supplicant`?

[edit]

I tried

```
wpa_cli -i "$INTERFACE" reconfigure
```

but that gave me

```
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlp2s3  error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `wpa_action "$INTERFACE" reload`

Comment: I'm getting `wpa_action: command not found`.

Comment: What distribution is this? How come they don't handle this seamlessly today? Have you looked for relevant bugs, or reported it?

Comment: Archlinux. Their forums are actually filled with unanswered WiFi problems, but it seems there should be some way to simply reset wpa-supplicant.

Comment: A lot depends on what configuration options `wpa_supplicant` and `dhcpcd` are called with - e.g. `dhcpcd -p` will it not to de-configure the device on exit.

Comment: you may want to poke around `/etc/netctl`.

Comment: Yes - that would be likely culprit! But for me, I got rid of that long ago. Gone. Byebye. History. Adios.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `wpa-supplicant` is not in fact retaining its settings, but instead is OVERRIDING `iwconfig`, and the SSID I pass to it.

When I pass a non-wpa SSID to `iwconfig`, `dhcpcd` by default invokes `wpa-supplicant` for all WiFi connections, then `wpa-s` goes down ITS list of the wpa networks I configured for it, and decides that I don't really want the open network I asked for.

Putting a "wildcard" network config into wpa-s's config file causes wpa-s to simply pick the closest open network, no matter what SSID I pass to it.

Removing the "wildcard" causes `wpa-s` to error out on the first (out-of-range) wpa network on the list, ignoring my SSID entirely.

This appears to be a violation of the Linux rule "do one thing and do it well" - `wpa-s` seems to be mission-creeping into network management, and doing the worst possible job of it imaginable!

I fixed this by adding `nohook wpa_supplicant` to my `dhcpcd` config file, and changing my "connect" script to only invoke wpa-supplicant for wpa networks.

```
sudo iwconfig "$INTERFACE" essid "$SSID" key "$PSK" 2>/dev/null
WPA=$(printf "$TABLE" | grep "$SSID" | cut -s -d $'\t' -f 2- | grep "WPA")
    if [[ $WPA ]]; then
        sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i "$INTERFACE" -c "$WPA_SUPPLICANT_CONFIGURATION_FILE"`
    fi
sudo dhcpcd "$INTERFACE"
```